# How to submit html form with Haskell

Tags: haskell

I know how to use [http-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.0) package's simplehttp to retrieve a page from an URL. Now what if on that
web page there is an input text field and a submit button. Can I also use http-conduit to fill that text field and push the button and retrieve the resulting page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use either [urlEncodedBody](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.0/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v%3aurlEncodedBody) or, for multipart messages, the [MultipartFormData](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.3.0.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Client-MultipartFormData.html) module.

Answer (score 2):

According to Snoyman, it seems you can do it with `http-conduit`. But you may want to look on [Sphider](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shpider) package which is developed specifically for that purpose. In fact, their hackage page has given an example for submitting html form:

```
runShpider $ do
      download "http://apage.com"
      theForm : _ <- getFormsByAction "http://anotherpage.com"
      sendForm $ fillOutForm theForm $ pairs $ do
            "occupation" =: "unemployed Haskell programmer"
            "location" =: "mother's house"
```