# Yesod, getting name-value map, containing HTML form values

Tags: haskell, yesod

What is the better way to get a map with POST form parameters is Yesod. I have a plain HTML form and submit it. In Yesod handler I want to get a map. The key will be the parameter name, the value - value for this name.

The `runInputPost` and `ireq`'s give me a parameter by name. But form may contain many params. I can't say, how many it will be in the handler at this request.

Comment: In Yesod, the general way to create form is using Record data structure. Once the form value is submitted, you get the record value wrapped in `FormSucess` data constructor. You can use the record functions to access them. So the question is, Why do you want `Map` instead of using the record ?

Comment: Thanks! But what about non-form way to getting data? curl, for example, or some another API for making request from remote application.

Comment: You can use sphider (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shpider) package for marking request from remote application. Another option would be http-client. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985481/how-to-submit-html-form-with-haskell/22986530#22986530

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [runRequestBody](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/yesod-core/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v%3arunRequestBody) to get direct access to all of the POST parameters and files.